# htaccess rewrite all pages except two

Tags: .htaccess

I have this code in my htaccess file:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} = 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^login/?$ login.php
RewriteRule ^logout/?$ logout.php

RewriteRule ^([\w/-]+)/?$ index.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]
```

So i want to rewrite all links to `index.php?id=LINK-HERE`

excluding /login and /logout which should rewrite to login.php and logout.php but they are not working. they seem to be using the ?id=...

Answer (score 1):

You can have it this way

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# remove those 2 following lines when running on localhost
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^admin\.integra-uk\.net$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^login/?$ login.php [L]
RewriteRule ^logout/?$ logout.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([\w/-]+)/?$ index.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: plus, its a website being hosted locally so don't need the host name. can this be removed?

Comment: What's the url you tried ? In which folder is your htaccess located ? Is there also other rules in your htaccess ?

Comment: Yep, in this case you need to remove it, otherwise you'll have what you get now

Comment: the link i tried was web-srv01/login - i have copied your code exactly, no other rules. this file is located in the same directory as index.php (root dir)

Comment: Ok, you can see my previous comment (as an answer to yours) and my edited code (in my answer) for more information. Should be working as expected

Comment: @CharlesF You're welcome ! Don't forget to validate my answer if you found it helpful, in order to mark your question as solved